# CakePHP: Testing Front End Pages

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I'd like to test all of the front-end pages on my site to ensure the user doesn't need to be logged in to access them. This is what I've come up with (which works), but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
public function testAboutUsPage() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/pages/about_us', array('return' => 'view'));

    if(! $result) {
        $this->assertFalse($result);
    }
}
```

If the page is not protected by the auth component, it will return the content for the view. If it is protected (requiring login), $result will be null.

Comment: What's the problem with your code specifically? If you outline it or ask a specific question on what you would like to improve you'll probably get an/a better answer.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. I am just wondering if there is a better/more proper way to do it. My code above feels like a small "hack"

Comment: I don't think that using Cake's test suite is a hack at all, if it works and achieves what you want then great.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, although you should be making some assertion regardless of whether you get a result or not. In your current code, you'll only enter your `if(! $result)` block if the result is false - which means that of course, the next line, `$this->assertFalse($result);` will pass. You've just checked it was false on the previous line!

When you test, you make an assertion which you expect to be valid. If your code is broken, your assertion will be invalid, and your test will fail.

I'd do this: (Note that the strings I've passed in as a second parameter to the `assert` calls are basically the error message you'll get if that code fails.)

To test a public page can be viewed:

```
public function testPublicPage() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/pages/public', array('return' => 'view'));
    $this->assertNotEmpty($result, "we were not able to view a public page");
}
```

And to test a private page can't be viewed:

```
public function testPrivatePage() {
    $result = $this->testAction('/pages/private', array('return' => 'view'));
    $this->assertNull($result, "we were able to view a private page");
}
```

One other thing to know about testing: you when you write a test, to make sure it's actually testing something you should both:

a) run it and make sure it passes
*and just as importantly:*
b) intentionally break your code that relates to that test, and make sure it fails.

Otherwise you don't know that your test is in fact testing anything! I won't go into "Test Driven Development" here - but basically it's the idea that you write your test first (before writing the code), run it to make sure it fails, then write your code until  your test passes. That's another good way of making sure you've got both a) and b) checked off.